# Remove red border from modeline

Tags: mode-line, colors

I have a red border around my modeline, and I don't like it. How can I get rid of it?

Emacs 24
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot, together with information about the emacs version and platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
                    :box '(:width 0))
```

Like upper code shows, you can change `mode-line` face, or `mode-line-inactive`. set border `box` to `0` or change border color to the same color with mode-line background.

You'd better take a screenshot to show how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Options > Customize Emacs > Specific Face > `mode-line` > Box around text