# Massively long text boxes and yasnippet highlighting

Tags: yasnippet, highlighting, custom

Why are my text boxes and `yasnippet` field highlights so massively long?

Is there a way to change this behavior?

If so, what are the necessary steps that need to be taken to solve this issue?

---

**The behavior can be seen like so:**

**When customizing:**

[image]

**When using `yasnippet`:**

[image]

Comment: Does this also happen when starting emacs without loading your init file: `emacs -q`?

Comment: @Hubisan Yes, it does.

Comment: Looks like this is normal, found a screenshot in an older question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17638/19819. At least in the customize interface. Not sure about the yasnippet one.

Comment: The field in the customize dialog is an [editable-field](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/widget/editable_002dfield.html#editable_002dfield) and by default the field will reach to the end of the line.